# GKE: Cannot mount /dev/sdb read-only when using a read-only GCP persistent disk based PV

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to mount a PV based on an existing GCP persistent disk onto my pod as read-only.
My configs look like this (Parts of them are masked for confidentiality)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: data-and-models-pv
  namespace: lipsync
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  claimRef:
    namespace: lipsync
    name: data-and-models-pvc
#  csi:
#    driver: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
#    volumeHandle: projects/***/zones/***/disks/g-lipsync-data-and-models
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: g-lipsync-data-and-models
    fsType: ext4
    readOnly: true
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: data-and-models-pvc
  namespace: lipsync
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

And then, in the pod definition:

```
  volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /app/models
        subPath: models
        name: data-and-models-v
        readOnly: true
      - [...]
volumes:
  - name: data-and-models-v
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: data-and-models-pvc
      readOnly: true
```

However, when I do kubectl apply, the pod never gets created, and I am met with this event:

```
0s          Warning   FailedMount              pod/lipsync-api-67c784dfb7-4tlln                 MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "data-and-models-pv" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = Failed to format and mount device from ("/dev/disk/by-id/google-g-lipsync-data-and-models") to ("/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/data-and-models-pv/globalmount") with fstype ("ext4") and options ([]): mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t ext4 -o defaults /dev/disk/by-id/google-g-lipsync-data-and-models /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/data-and-models-pv/globalmount
Output: mount: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/data-and-models-pv/globalmount: cannot mount /dev/sdb read-only.
```

If I manually ssh into the VM that acts as the node that supports the pod, I can observe that adding noload to the mount options can make me successfully mount the disk:

```
sudo mount -o ro,noload,defaults /dev/sdb .
```

But I am not aware of any way to make Kubernetes use this extra mount option.

How can I sucessfully make GKE mount this disk to my pod?

Comment: Is the persistent disk partitioned and formatted with a file system?

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes. It is partitioned and formatted with ext4, and is populated with files

Comment: `/dev/sdb`/ is the entire disk. Mount the partition with a file system that would look like `/dev/sdb1`.

Comment: @JohnHanley Sorry, I misunderstood the question. The disk is NOT partitioned (no partition table), just formatted as a whole.

Comment: UPDATE: this is the next morning, and the disk now works. In the mean time, I have only mounted the disk onto a different VM, found one file buried deep inside with 600 (rw-------) permission and changed it to 664 (rw-rw-r--). I doubt this is what fixed it...

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the readOnly mode today. Hope my experience can give you some idea.

I have two snapshots, one is created by someone else, and the other is created by me. The files on both disks are identical.

But when I mounted the disk provisioned by the screenshot that the other created, the `readOnly` works fine. But mine just kept getting the same error you have.

So I logged in the pod without `readOnly` mode to see the difference between the two disks. And the only difference I found is the good one has `userId: 1003` and `groupId 1004` and mine is `root:root`. So I ran `chown 1003:1004 -R ./` to my disk, used it to create a new snapshot, and then it worked smoothly...

I haven't found the reason yet, but it worked at least. Will let you know if i figure out.

Comment: i just checked the uid/gid of root user, it's `0:0` so it might be the problem?

Comment: I must admit, this is really weird, i thought i just couldn't user/group `0:0`, but I tried with 1001:1001, it didn't work either... somehow, it has to be `1003:1004`?

Comment: Very interesting... Can you find out what these user id and group id correspond to in your setup?

Comment: Just checked the permissions... In my case, the disk already has 1003:1004, but those actually correspond to another user of the system in my case.

Comment: 1003:1004 doesn't exist in my pod, neither the user, nor the group. so maybe it needs some new uid and gid? Have you tried to change the ownership to some non-existing user/group?

Comment: I mounted the disk onto a different VM, found one file buried deep inside with 600 (rw-------) permission and changed it to 664 (rw-rw-r--). And now the disk works in GKE. I doubt this is what fixed it though...

Comment: @EricYang Can you add this info to the answer? (that it might be owner but also permissions)

Answer (score 0):

You can include mount options in your [StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) definition using the `mountOptions` field.

Here is an example with GCE Balanced PD when I wanted to include the `discard` mount option:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: pd-balanced
  namespace: blog-ns
provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - discard
parameters:
  type: pd-balanced
```

Later, when you reference this `StorageClass` in other resources it'll cause the mount options to be included when actually mounting the storage on a node.

Specifically for read-only disks GKE (maybe inheriting from k8s, don't know actually) will automatically add the `norecovery` option for you as well to decrease mount failures when the filesystem is dirty.

Hope this helps. From the discussion it wasn't clear if filesystem permissions or read-only aspects were to blame, but as I just wrote a [blog about read-only persistent disks](https://www.beginswithdata.com/2023/11/20/google-cloud-read-only-disk/) I wanted to share what I've learned recently.